# Get all tr on page by class

Tags: java, htmlunit

I need to get all tables with some class, and get all id of rows with some class in this tables. My code is next:

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.somesite.com");
HtmlTable table = div.querySelector(".table-classname");
for (HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows())
{
String id = row.getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(id);
}
```

But it works only for first table on the page. How can i do this with all tables on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` and iterate through the list of returned elements